# Swift 3.0 SpriteKit > apply impulse with force?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift3

tl:dr - how do I apply an initial force to speed up a sprite in my game?

I am working through this tutorial to build a sprite kit based game. [Link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/123393/how-to-create-a-breakout-game-with-sprite-kit-and-swift)

I have followed everything exactly, and it was working fine up until I got to removing the gravity, and adding an impulse to the ball.

The issue is that the ball is moving very very slowly. When add the gravity back into the game the ball once again moves at a regular speed.

How do I apply an impulse to the ball so it moves fast from the beginning? In the tutorial the gif's show the ball moving at a high speed without an extra code. So maybe I am doing something wrong.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {



override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

super.didMove(to: view)


let borderBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: self.frame)

borderBody.friction = 0

self.physicsBody = borderBody

physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: 0.0)

let ball = childNode(withName: BallCategoryName) as! SKSpriteNode
ball.physicsBody!.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 2.0, dy: -2.0))

  }

}
```

Comment: Your force is very weak,  Gravity is 9.8 m/s,  you are moving it at like 2.8m/s,  The reason it works fast with gravity is because gravity is helping you out, by bumping the acceleration to 12.6m/s

Comment: @Knight0fDragon - How do I increase the speed of the ball to make it go 12.6m/s from the get go?

Comment: Try adding zeros to these numbers: applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 2.0, dy: -2.0)

Comment: How do you make a car go faster?  give it some more gas.  Make the applyImpulse a larger number

Comment: the reason I say 2.8 is because it is sqrt(2 squared + 2 squared)  and the value isnt really 12.6m/s  I just didnt feel like doing the math lol

Comment: Ok thanks. Making it 20 seems to sped it up a bit. I'll play with different numbers... But now the problem is, the ball is not bouncing around the edges like its supposed to...

Comment: That seems like a separate question, that really depends on how your walls physics bodies are set up and collisions bit masks

Answer (score 0):

"How do I apply an impulse to the ball so it moves fast from the beginning? **In the tutorial the gif's show the ball moving at a high speed without an extra code.** So maybe I am doing something wrong."

My guess is you have copied your tutors code exactly but the ball is moving slowly? In that case the problem is with the node BallCategoryName itself. I am guessing the ball probably weighs more when you designed it compared to your instructor who most likely made it smaller in mass so it moves faster with little impulse. 
From the code you have, you have no gravity actually. So there is no gravity in PhysicsWorld. My advice for you would be to leave the gravity,and impulse alone and try to get the right mass by changing the mass of the ball. That is most likely where you and your instructors have difference.